# ASP.NET Check if Selected User in ListBox is in Role

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using VS2005 C# ASP.NET.

I have a webform which contains a list of users in a ListBox tool.

I would like to check if the selected user in the ListBox is in a specific role, how can I do it?

Below is my current code:

```
if (UsersListBox.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UsersListBox.SelectedItem.Value);

            //check if the selected user is in role "Administrator"

        }
```

I have tried using `this.User.IsInRole("Administrators")`. However it will only retrieve the role of the active user instead of the selected user in the ListBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   if(Roles.IsUserInRole(UserListBox.SelectedItem.Value,"Administrator"))
    {
      //
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (UsersListBox.SelectedItem != null) 
{ 
    string[] rolesArray = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UsersListBox.SelectedItem.Value); 

    if (rolesArray.Contains("Administrator"))
    {
        // do something if user is Admin
    }
    else
    {
        // user is not Admin
    }
}
```

Comment: it says `System.Array` does not contain a definition for 'Contains', did I miss out something?